# Adding jars to WEB-INF/lib folder using Maven

Tags: java, maven

I created a Dynamic Web Project. Then Convert to Maven Project. I added Struts 2 dependency in my POM.

But when I right click on project and Run On Server I get HTTP Status 404

However, if I disable Maven Nature and manually add Struts 2 jars to my  build path and WEB-INF/lib directory it works. Below is my POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Struts2MultipleFilesUpload</groupId>
  <artifactId>Struts2MultipleFilesUpload</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
  <version>3.9</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>    
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: First suggestion is. Follow conventions. means sourcecode into `src/main/java`. parts for war source `src/main/webapp`...make a `mvn clean package` on command line and check the content of the war file itself...